# Why is reading from IBM MQ queue extremely slow using .NET standard library? (unlike .NET)

Tags: c#, .net, websphere, ibm-mq

I wrote a console app on .NET, to read without consuming the messages from an IBM MQ queue.

Worked perfect.

Now, I need to migrate that app into .NET Core. Can't figure out why it is extremely slow.

How it works:

- target framework .NET Core 3.1
- IBMMQDotNetClient NuGet package installed
- created a helper class, static, with a static constructor where I initialise MQEnvironment properties like so:

```
    MQEnvironment.CertificateLabel = "ibmwebsphere"; // this is the friendlyname on mmc certificate
    MQEnvironment.SSLKeyRepository = "*SYSTEM";
```

- added a method called Init where I initialise connection to MQManager like so:

```
    Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
    properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
    properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName); // I read the hostName from a config file
    properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port); // I read the port from a config file
    properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channelName); // I read the channel from a config file
    properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, cipherSpec); // I read the cipher spec from a config file, it's something like TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
```

Then, I'm going to create a connection to the queue manager using the connection, and read messages one by one until coming to end of the queue.

```
var queueManager = new MQQueueManager(qm, properties); // I read the qm from a config file
var queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_BROWSE + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING); // I read the queueName from a config file
var mqGMO = new MQGetMessageOptions();
mqGMO.Options = MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + MQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT + MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT; mqGMO.MatchOptions = MQC.MQMO_NONE;


try {

    while (true) {

        MQMessage queueMessage = new MQMessage();
        queue.Get(queueMessage, mqGMO); // code gets apparently stuck on this line, 
// overprocessing, for many minutes until it gets to the next line, 
// even though I mentioned "NO_WAIT" in the options. 
// Note this only happens for .NET Core, but not in .NET framework. 
        var message = queueMessage.ReadString(queueMessage.MessageLength);
        string fileName = message.Substring(0,3); // some processing here to extract some info from each message
    }
}
catch(MQException ex) 
{
    if(err.ReasonCode.CompareTo(MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE) == 0)
    {
        // harmless exception to indicate there are no messages on the queue
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Of course it would be preferable to use a listener, not sure how to do that yet, it would be part of optimising, but for now - why is working so slow on line:
`queue.Get(queueMessage, mqGMO);`  // but, again, as mentioned, only with the amqmdnetstd.dll (.NET Core), because if I use amqmdnet.dll (.NET framework), it works super fast, and it's supposed to be the other way around.

I do need to use .NET Standard/Core because I will run this in Linux, currently testing in Windows.

Comment: What version of `amqmdnetstd.dll` are you using?

Comment: MQGMO needs to be reinitialized before every get. Have you tried to by moving var mqGMO = new MQGetMessageOptions();
mqGMO.Options = MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + MQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT + MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT; mqGMO.MatchOptions = MQC.MQMO_NONE;
inside the while loop?

Comment: @Shashi note he has `mqGMO.MatchOptions = MQC.MQMO_NONE` so that should not be causing him any issues.   From the MQ Docs "The initial value of the MatchOptions field is defined for compatibility with earlier MQSeries® queue managers. However, when reading a series of messages from a queue without using selection criteria, this initial value requires the application to reset the MsgId and CorrelId fields to MQMI_NONE and MQCI_NONE before each MQGET call. Avoid the need to reset MsgId and CorrelId by setting Version to MQGMO_VERSION_2, and MatchOptions to MQMO_NONE."

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the MQEnvironment class as it is not threaded safe. Also, don't mix and match between MQEnvironment class and using MQ HashTable.  Put your SSL/TLS information as a property in the MQ HashTable.

i.e.

```
properties.Add(MQC.SSL_PEER_NAME_PROPERTY, "ibmwebsphere");
properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, "*SYSTEM");
```

There isn't enough of your code to test to see why it might be failing.

I wrote and posted a blog item called: [IBM MQ For .NET Core Primer](https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=6879).  In the blog post, I included a fully functioning C# MQ example (MQTest62L.cs) that was built and run using .NET Core v3.1 and everything worked perfectly (see very bottom of post).  Hence, I would suggest you follow my instructions, download, compile and run MQTest62L.cs to see if the issue is your code or MQ Client library.

Note: I was using Windows 10 Pro, IBM MQ v9.2.0.0 and .NET Core v3.1.415.